# Software Updater gui app suggestions get stale when updates get done on command line

Tags: command-line, apt, updates

Is there a way to configure `Software Updater` gui app to auto refresh its proposed updates ?  Since it shows stale update suggestions when I have already run the updates on command line.

When I see `Software Updater` gui app wiggling, then I run this on command line

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade &&  [ -f /var/run/reboot-required ] && echo && echo reboot required && echo
```

I still see `Software Updater` gui app wiggling about prompting me to do a list of updates which where just executed.  If `Software Updater` could refresh its list of proposed updates it would recognize there is nothing to do, stop wiggling and users would enjoy greater feng shui

Is there a better solution than to kill off `System Updater` process when command line updates get run ?

Comment: It refreshes if closed and then reopened ;) but I'm sure this isn't what you want. However, if you really think about it you'd easily understand it depends on running `apt update` and it can't be doing that all time just to refresh, otherwise you'd never be able to use it to actually install the pending updates.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't. When `Software Updater` starts, it computes the upgrade, displays the list and waits for your input.

One could always exit and restart Software Updater.